# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

when I write this code: (my entire code, school project on Augmented Reality)
Everything worked perfectly until I tried to run the video.
...........................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(2)                                         
imgTarget=cv2.imread('F1racecars.jpeg')                         
vidTarget= cv2.VideoCapture('F1racecars.mp4')
               
success, vidTarget = vidTarget.read()                           
imgTarget=cv2.resize(imgTarget,(640,360))                       
hT, wT, cT = imgTarget.shape   
vidTarget=cv2.resize(vidTarget,(wT,hT))                        


orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=1000)
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(imgTarget,None)

detect = False
fcount = 0


while True:                                                     
   success, imgWebcam= cap.read()                              
   imgAug = imgWebcam.copy()

   imgWarp = np.zeros((imgWebcam.shape[1], imgWebcam.shape[0],imgWebcam.shape[2]))
   masknew = np.zeros((imgWebcam.shape[0], imgWebcam.shape[1],imgWebcam.shape[2]), np.uint8)
   maskInv = np.zeros((imgWebcam.shape[0], imgWebcam.shape[1], imgWebcam.shape[2]), np.uint8)
   Mergecamfeed =  np.zeros((imgWebcam.shape[0], imgWebcam.shape[1], imgWebcam.shape[2]), np.uint8)
   ARfinal = np.zeros((imgWebcam.shape[0], imgWebcam.shape[1], imgWebcam.shape[2]), np.uint8)

   if detect is False:
      vidTarget.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,0)
      fcount =0
   else:
      if fcount == vidTarget.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT, 0):
         vidTarget.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
         fcount = 0
   success, vidTarget= vidTarget.read()
   vidTarget= cv2.resize(vidTarget, (wT, hT))

   kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(imgWebcam,None)

   if des2 is None: print(False)
   else:
      bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
      featmatch = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
      good=[]
      for m,n in featmatch:
          if m.distance < 0.75 * n.distance: good.append(m)
      print(len(good))

      if len(good)>20:                                                                
         detect = True
         srcpts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
         dstpts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

         matrix, mask = cv2.findHomography(srcpts,dstpts, cv2.RANSAC, 5)
         print(matrix)

         pts = np.float32([[0,0],[0,360],[640,360],[640,0]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

         dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,matrix)
         cv2.polylines(imgWebcam,[np.int32(dst)],True,(255,0,255),3)

         imgWarp = cv2.warpPerspective(vidTarget,matrix, (imgWebcam.shape[1],imgWebcam.shape[0]))

         cv2.fillPoly(masknew, [np.int32(dst)], (255,255,255))

         maskInv = cv2.bitwise_not(masknew)

         Mergecamfeed = cv2.bitwise_and(imgAug,imgAug,None, mask = maskInv[:,:,0])
                                                                            
         ARfinal = cv2.bitwise_or(imgWarp, Mergecamfeed)                     


   cv2.imshow('imgTarget', imgTarget)
   cv2.imshow('imgTargetVdo', vidTarget)
   cv2.imshow('webcam', imgWebcam)
   cv2.imshow('warp', imgWarp)
   cv2.imshow('mask', masknew)
   cv2.imshow('Modified mask', maskInv)
   cv2.imshow('Aug Image', Mergecamfeed)
   cv2.imshow('Augmented Reality Final O/P', ARfinal)
   cv2.waitKey(1)
   fcount += 1
```

It shows like this:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set'
```

Comment: you seem to confuse the VideoCapture instance with an image you read from it

Comment: Provide a proper [mcve]. I can fairly confidently guess that problem is in `success, imgVideo = imgVideo.read()` where you reassign `imgVideo` from what was likely a `VideoCapture` instance to a retrieved frame, but since there's no loop in your out-of-context snippet of code, that wouldn't in itself cause a problem.

Comment: Should i share my entire code? so u can help. I will just edit my question. Try helping pls

Comment: please do not reuse variable names (imgVideo) for different purpose. you been shooting your own foot this way

Comment: "Should i share my entire code?" -- no, a [mcve]. The page describes what that means. Right now, it won't even run (missing imports, several undefined variables), let alone reproduce the problem (you overwrite `imgVideo` after calling `set`, so there's probably a loop missing too). You should be able to paste the code you provide into a new file, and when you run that file (without having to modify anything), it should produce the exact error you mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally we ask for the full error message, with traceback.  That makes it easier to identify where the error occurs.  In this case though, `set` is only used a couple of times.

```
vidTarget.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,0)
```

What's this thing `vidTarget`?  The error says it's a `numpy` array, and is clear that such an object does not have a `set` method.  Experienced `numpy` users also know that.  So what kind of object did you expect it to be?

We see attribute errors for one of two reasons.  Either the code writer did not read the documentation, and tried to use a non-existent method.  Or the variable in question is not what he expected.  You should know, at every, step what the variable is - not just guess or hope, **know**.  Test if necessary.

## edit

Initially

```
vidTarget= cv2.VideoCapture('F1racecars.mp4')
```

From a quick read of `cv2` docs, this has `get/set` methods

but then you do

```
succses, vidTarget = vidTarget.read()
# and resize
```

That redefines `vidTarget`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, I will keep that advice in my mind. I followed this tutorial, around 11:20 he does the same thing that I have done, but it works for him, pls check out and help Me pls. video link: https://youtu.be/Gz0vJRaz2l4